# reverse proxying with NGINX to two back-end servers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to learn how to configure the Nginx proxy. All requests from external (www.external.com) should go to internal server 10.10.10.16:2080, except for www.external.com/nagios requests, which should go to internal 10.10.10.18.

My location block looks as follows:

```
    location ~* / {
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.16:2080;
        }       

    # # nagios server
    location  ~* /nagios/  {
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_buffering off;
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.18;
        }
```

The first location seems to work fine. However, any request to *www.external.com/nagios* sends the browser into the eternal pastures. Of course, *10.10.10.18/nagios* was tested and works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: In the meantime I have found that if I comment out the 1st location, then the nagios location works. But wasn't Nginx supposed to use the more specific location if the request satisfies both?

Comment: Why you use regexp locations. They are checked in order and first match win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn how Nginx handle location. See this [old wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) or [new one](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) or [this blog](http://fisharebest.stonystratford.org/116/understanding-nginx-location-rules/).

The summary:

> There are 4 types of location rule, and are applied with the following priorities:
>
> 1. **Exact matches:** There can be only one exact match – the clue is in the name!. For example:
>
>    location = /foo/bar
> 2. **High priority prefix:** There can be more than one match, the longest one takes priority. For example:
>
>    location ^~ /foo
> 3. **Regex:** There can be more than one match, the first one found takes priority. There are two variants
>
>    location ~ .foo$ (case-sensitive regex)
>
>    location ~* .foo$ (case-insensitive regex)
> 4. **Low priority prefix:** There can be more than one match, the longest one takes priority. For example
>
>    location /foo

In your case, here the logic pseudo code of request processing:

```
if location begins with string /nagios:
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.18;
else
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.16:2080;
```

That logic can be translated to nginx config with below.

**Edit: Based on comment below from Tero Kilkanen, we can remove regex-matching in this case thus saving some CPU resources. In this case, we only using rule** `Low priority prefix`

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.16:2080;
}

location /nagios {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://10.10.10.18;
}
```

Comment: One does not need any regex matching here. So, for nagios, `location /nagios` is enough.

Comment: Thank you to masegaloeh and all other commenters for your time and conmpetent help, which is very much appreciated. The issue is resolved!